# How to save WAV Blob to MongoDB, retrieve and serve correctly with Node?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, recorder.js

I've found many posts dealing with saving binary files using the Mongoose Buffer SchemaType. However, most of them deal with image files, and I haven't been able to get them to work with a WAV audio file.

I'm using Recorder.js to save audio recordings from the built-in microphone. I use Recorder.js' exportWAV function to get a BLOB from the finished recording, then read the blob with FileReader and send it to the Node/Express backend where it is then saved to the DB. I've checked using the Mongo CLI and there is data being saved to the relevant field (starting with BinData(0,"UklGR.lotsofdatahere..="). When I try to get the recording by sentence id, the server responds with an appropriately-MIME-typed .wav file that is unplayable.

It seems that I'm missing something in the way that the files are encoded and decoded for storage in MongoDB. When reading the blob spit out by Recorder.js, it looks like it's already base64 encoded. So that's why I tried loading it as a base64 Buffer before saving to Mongo, and then decoding from a base64 buffer on output. What am I missing here? How can I fix these encoding issues? Thanks!

Note: I don't necessarily need GridFS because these files are well under 16MB. Although, if it's a lot faster to stream files from GridFS, maybe I should switch to that solution. However, I'd like to figure out what's wrong with this approach first.

Here's the relevant code from the Angular frontend:

```js
$scope.start = function() {
  $scope.rec.record();
}

$scope.export = function() {
  $scope.rec.stop();

  $scope.rec.exportWAV(function blobCallback(blob) {
    $scope.rec.clear();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/saveRecording',
        data: {
          audio: event.target.result,
          text: $scope.text,
          timestamp: new Date()
        }
      }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}
```

The Express routes:

```js
router.post('/saveRecording', function(request, response, next) {
  var sentence = new Sentence();
  sentence.audio = new Buffer(request.body.audio, 'base64');
  sentence.timestamp = request.body.timestamp;
  sentence.text = request.body.text;


  // Save sentence to DB with Mongoose
  sentence.save(function(error, sentence) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    }

    // If no error, send added sentence back to the client.
    response.json(sentence);
  });
});

router.get('/getRecording/:sentenceId', function(request, response, next) {
  Sentence.findById(request.params.sentenceId,
    function dbCallback (error, sentence) {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      }
      if (!sentence) {
        return next(new Error('Can\'t find sentence'));
      }

      var base64Audio = new Buffer(sentence.audio, 'base64');
      response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/x-wav',
        'Content-Length': base64Audio.length
      });

      response.write(base64Audio);
      response.end();
    });
});
```

The Mongoose Schema for Sentences:

```js
var SentenceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  audio: Buffer,
  timestamp: Date
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using GridFs for storing your audio files
check that [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)

Comment: I've considered GridFS, but I don't think it's really necessary for the small file sizes I'm using. I would appreciate any guidance as to what's going wrong with my encoding/decoding in the above code examples.

Comment: Have you tried to read the blob as BufferArray ?
 reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)

Comment: I tried the BufferArray thing, but couldn't quite get it working. In that case, I'd have to convert from BufferArray to a Node Buffer anyways, which from what I've read can be slow. I followed your original advice and ended up using GridFS which is now working like a charm... I would say in the future I wouldn't bother trying to do it manually, even with small file sizes. The performance difference is probably negligible for what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: Great that it is working with you now! I have found that GridFs is a better way to deal with all sizes of files even the small ones.